# NgZone is undefined in service

Tags: angular

I have a service like this:

```
import {Injectable, NgZone} from "@angular/core";
import {Mediafilepicker} from "nativescript-mediafilepicker";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {NO_IMAGE_SELECTED} from "~/mediapicker.service";

@Injectable()
export class MediaPicker {
    constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

    pick(types, page) {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            const picker = new Mediafilepicker();

            picker.on('getFiles', (res: any) => {
                this.zone.run(() => {
                    if (!res.files.length) {
                        observer.error(NO_IMAGE_SELECTED);
                        return;
                    }

                    observer.next(res.files.split(',')[0]);
                    observer.complete();
                })
            });

            picker.on("error", res => {
                this.zone.run(() => {
                    observer.error(res);
                    observer.complete();
                });
            });

            picker.startFilePicker({
                android: {
                    enableImagePicker: !types || types.length == 2 || (types.length == 1 && types[0] == 'image'),
                    enableVideoPicker: !types || types.length == 2 || (types.length == 1 && types[0] == 'video'),
                    enableCameraSupport: true,
                    mxcount: 1,
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

It crashes when the callback on "getFiles" is called, with the error "Cannot read property "run" of undefined".

How can it be that zone is undefined in this service?

Edit: this only seems to be an issue with AOT. Everything works fine with JIT

Comment: Are you sure you can even use NgZone inside a singleton (@Injectable) class? I don't think you can. What do you even need NgZone for in your example?

Comment: @Carsten the callback is ran outside the zone, and I want to make sure the zone is run when continuing execution

Answer (score 1):

I'll try (but I don't know if work :( )

```
return Observable.create(observer => {
        const picker = new Mediafilepicker();
        //Use an auxiliar variable
        let zone=this.zone; //here I'm sure this.zone is really this.zone
        picker.on('getFiles', (res: any) => {
            zone.run(() => {  //<--use zone, not this.zone
                ...
            })
        })
        ...
        })
```

Comment: Tried that, but it doesn't work. `this.zone` is undefined everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this for my SignalR-driven data updates that weren't being propagated to the browser, despite the appearance of being "handled" correctly.

It does seem as suggested by @Carsten that you can't use NgZone inside a singleton service. The solution is simply to inject NgZone into the component that consumes the Observable (in the OP's case - "observer.next(res.files.split(',')[0]);").

Example here...

**Service:**
(extract)

```js
private messageSource: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
message$: Observable<any> = this.messageSource.asObservable();
constructor() {
    let url = "/signalr";
    this.connection = $.hubConnection(url);
    this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy('notificationHub');
    this.proxy.on('receiveMessage', function (message) {

       // NgZone doesn't work here in the service
       this.messageSource.next(message);
    });
}
```

**Component:**
(extract)

```js
messageSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(private _service: NotificationService, private _ngZone: NgZone) {
    this.messageSubscription = this._service.message$
      .subscribe((message) => {

        // NgZone works perfectly here in the component, 
        // and the display component updates automatically as expected
        _ngZone.run(() => this.handleDataUpdate(message));
      });
  }
```